# WP Cron in Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I've been using [this WP plugin boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) for some time and now I have a problem that I can't seem to solve, so I would appreciate any help.

In includes there's a file called *class-plugin-name-activator.php* and in it there's a class called *Plugin_Name_Activator* and a public static function called activate.

I've added [wp_schedule_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event), like this:

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'rs_license_daily_event' );
```

... in the activate function. Also, I've added two public static functions after activate functions, the first one is calling the other. Let's say the first function name is rs_license_do_daily_event.

Now, I need to use add_action like this:

```
add_action( 'rs_license_daily_event', 'rs_license_do_daily_event' );
```

How can I do it so it works?

Also, I'm using a plugin called WP Crontrol to test run the cron manually so I can see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside public static function activate add:

```
public static function activate() {

        $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'rs_license_daily_event' );

        if($timestamp == false) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'rs_license_daily_event' );
        }
}
```

then in admin or public part add: (public part example)

```
private function define_public_hooks() {

        $plugin_public = new Plugin_Name_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
        $this->loader->add_action( 'rs_license_daily_event', $plugin_public, 'rs_license' );

    }
```

and finaly in public class add that method:

```
public function rs_license() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.